# replace values of a list with another in R

Tags: r, list

a,b and c are list.

```
a<-list(c(6,5,7),c(1,2),c(1,3,4))
b<-list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5),c(6,7,8))
c<-list(1,2,2)
```

I want to replace "a" with "b" at place "c" to generate a new list.

The expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 5 7

[[2]]
[1] 1 5

[[3]]
[1] 1 7 4
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your replacement logic?

Comment: `Map(\`[<-\`, a, c, Map('[[', b, c))`

Comment: list "c" is the indicator of position, it contains 3 objects: 1,2 and 2.  They stand for the replacing element's position in each object of "a" and "b". That is to say, the first element of the first object in "a" (6) will be replaced by the first element of the first object in "b" (1),   the second element of the second object in "a" (2) will be replaced by the second element of the second object in "b" (5),  and the second element of the third object in "a" (3) will be replaced by the second element of the third object in "b" (7)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `Map` to iterate over all the lists simultaneously.

```
Map(function(a,b,c) {a[c]<-b[c]; a},a,b,c)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 5 7
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 5
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 7 4
```

Answer (score 0):

For the R newbies that find that find the syntax of `Map` daunting:

```
for(i in seq(c)){
  a[[i]][unlist(c[i])] <- b[[i]][unlist(c[i])]
}
a

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 5 7
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 5
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 7 4
```